# Simple react component fails to read state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a login component that I have reduced to the following definition for clarity

```
import React from "react";

export default class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userName: '',
        };
        this.updateUserName = this.updateUserName.bind(this);
    }

    onClickSignUp() {
        console.log(this.state);
        alert("clicked sign up with value: username=" + this.state.userName);
    }
    updateUserName(e) {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            userName: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="LoginComponent">
                <h1>Welcome!</h1>

                <div className="UserNameSegment">
                    <text>UserName: </text>
                    <input id="UserNameInput" value={this.state.userName} onChange={e => this.updateUserName(e)} />
                </div>

                <div className="ButtonGroup">
                    <button id="SignUpButton" onClick={this.onClickSignUp}>Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Intended functionality is that when I click the sign up button, it displays an alert that informs me of the user name that was typed into the input.  Currently when I enter some text and click on the sign up button the app crashes and tells me that I haven't defined the state of the LoginComponent: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`.  I feel like I've defined the state in the constructor... are there instances where the constructor wouldn't be called? What am I missing here?

Comment: You can use arrow function insead of bind. That will fix your problem and make more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot this line `this.onClickSignUp = this.onClickSignUp.bind(this);` in the `constructor` function.

Answer (score 1):

Change onClickSignUp to:

```
onClickSignUp = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    alert("clicked sign up with value: username=" + 
this.state.userName);
}
```